# While loop not exiting as expected

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop

Hello sorry for the beginner question but this has left me scratching my head. I previously tried using the break statement within an if statement to exit the code but was breaking regardless of the input. That code looked like this:

```
def describePet(petBreed, petName):
    print('I have a pet ' + petBreed)
    print('My ' + petBreed + '\'s name is ' + petName + '.')


while True:
    print('Type quit to exit.')
    breed = input('What is your pets breed?: ')
    name = input('What is your pets name?: ')
    if name or breed == 'quit':
        break
    else:
        describePet(breed, name)

print('test')
```

I was close to posting that as a question but have since reformatted it (however I would still appreciate an answer) in such a way that I get the desired output but am unable to break from the loop when entering the expected exit statement. The redone code looks like this:

```
def describePet(petBreed, petName):
    print('I have a pet ' + petBreed)
    print('My ' + petBreed + '\'s name is ' + petName + '.')


breed = None
name = None
while breed or name != 'quit':
    print('Type quit to exit.')
    breed = input('What is your pets breed?: ')
    name = input('What is your pets name?: ')
    describePet(breed, name)

print('test')
```

if you could please let me know why this code is not exiting when I store the string quit in either variable, it would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: please correct if condition like this `if name == 'quit' or breed == 'quit'`. same logical error in `while` condition.

Comment: `while breed or name != 'quit'` will not work as you expect. It will check if `breed` exists or `name` is not 'quit'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try these steps to in  your code. 
1. In the first part of your code change the if condition as follows.  (if name =='quit'  or breed == 'quit')

```
def describePet(petBreed, petName):
  print('I have a pet ' + petBreed)
  print('My ' + petBreed + '\'s name is ' + petName + '.')

  while True:
    print('Type quit to exit.')
    breed = input('What is your pets breed?: ')
    name = input('What is your pets name?: ')
    if name =='quit'  or breed == 'quit':
        break
    else:
        describePet(breed, name)
```

2. And then modify the while loop condition as follows.

   while breed != 'quit' or name != 'quit'

Answer (score 1):

Inside the while loop, do something like this:

```
def describePet(petBreed, petName):
print('I have a pet ' + petBreed)
print('My ' + petBreed + '\'s name is ' + petName + '.')


while True:
    print('Type quit to exit.')
    breed = input('What is your pets breed?: ')
    name = input('What is your pets name?: ')
    if name == 'quit' or breed == 'quit':
        break
    else:
        describePet(breed, name)

print('test')
```

using something like `name or breed == 'quit'` will never evaluate to true, because it will first evaluate `name or breed` which will always be a boolean value and this is not what you're expecting.

Comment: ahh okay I understand now. Thank you for that.

Comment: You can upvote the answer so that it can be helpful to others as well.

Comment: I have but as my reputation is so low it does not show publicly.